# How do I get the max record from a inner joined field, SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery, max

I need to pull the MAX seendate from a subquery it looks like and I can do it for a specific Item but as soon as I take away the WHERE clause for a specific Item, it does not display anything see below:

```
  SELECT Item.Barcode,
  Hetype.Description,
  StockTakeDetails.SeenDate,
  Users.UserName,
  defcon.Defcon_text,
  JOBS.Job_Ref,
  JOBS."Due Back"
FROM Item
  INNER JOIN Hetype ON Item.Type = Hetype.Type
  INNER JOIN StockTakeDetails ON Item.Itemref = StockTakeDetails.xItemID
  INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UID = StockTakeDetails.xUserSeen
  INNER JOIN EQLISTS ON Item.CurrentJob = EQLISTS.Eql_no
  INNER JOIN JOBS ON EQLISTS.Job_no = JOBS.JobNo
  INNER JOIN defcon ON JOBS.Status = defcon.Defcon_idx
WHERE JOBS."Due Back" >= TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND
  JOBS.Status <> 5 AND
  Item.Barcode = '038223' AND
  StockTakeDetails.IDX = (SELECT Max(StockTakeDetails.IDX)
  FROM StockTakeDetails INNER JOIN Item ON StockTakeDetails.xItemID =
      Item.Itemref WHERE Item.Barcode = '038223')
```

This works fine, how ever if I take out the Barcode clause it does not show any data:

```
SELECT Item.Barcode,
  Hetype.Description,
  StockTakeDetails.SeenDate,
  Users.UserName,
  defcon.Defcon_text,
  JOBS.Job_Ref,
  JOBS."Due Back"
FROM Item
  INNER JOIN Hetype ON Item.Type = Hetype.Type
  INNER JOIN StockTakeDetails ON Item.Itemref = StockTakeDetails.xItemID
  INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UID = StockTakeDetails.xUserSeen
  INNER JOIN EQLISTS ON Item.CurrentJob = EQLISTS.Eql_no
  INNER JOIN JOBS ON EQLISTS.Job_no = JOBS.JobNo
  INNER JOIN defcon ON JOBS.Status = defcon.Defcon_idx
WHERE JOBS."Due Back" >= TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND
  JOBS.Status <> 5 AND
  StockTakeDetails.IDX = (SELECT Max(StockTakeDetails.IDX)
  FROM StockTakeDetails INNER JOIN Item ON StockTakeDetails.xItemID =
      Item.Itemref)
```

please let me know how else I can do this.

Thank you

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you *just* need and max StockDetails seendate?

```
SELECT 
   Item.Barcode
   ,max(StockTakeDetails.IDX) as max_idx
FROM StockTakeDetails 
INNER JOIN Item 
   ON StockTakeDetails.xItemID = Item.Itemref 
GROUP BY Item.Barcode
```

Instead of using this query as a single-value filter in your WHERE, you could join this subquery in on both Barcode and max_idx.

Alternatively, you could modify you're major query to have it group by whatever the relevant unique fields are, and take the `max(StockTakeDetails.SeenDate)`

Answer (score 2):

This ended up working for what I needed Thank you all, all answers helped me get here.

```
SELECT i1.Barcode,
  Max(StockTakeDetails.SeenDate),
  Hetype.Description
FROM Item i1
  INNER JOIN Hetype ON i1.Type = Hetype.Type
  LEFT JOIN StockTakeDetails ON i1.Itemref = StockTakeDetails.xItemID
  INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UID = StockTakeDetails.xUserSeen
  INNER JOIN EQLISTS ON i1.CurrentJob = EQLISTS.Eql_no
  INNER JOIN JOBS ON EQLISTS.Job_no = JOBS.JobNo
  INNER JOIN defcon ON JOBS.Status = defcon.Defcon_idx
WHERE JOBS."Due Back" >= TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND
  JOBS.Status <> 5
GROUP BY i1.Barcode,
  JOBS."Due Back",
  JOBS.Status,
  Hetype.Description
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you need `GROUP BY Item.Barcode` at the end of the subquery, where you replaced the specific item code. When you took it out, you're passing a single value back for the entire table, instead of one max detail per barcode.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you need to constrain Barcode in the subquery. Note aliases, always use table aliases to avoid confusion

```
  SELECT i1.Barcode,
  Hetype.Description,
  StockTakeDetails.SeenDate,
  Users.UserName,
  defcon.Defcon_text,
  JOBS.Job_Ref,
  JOBS."Due Back"
FROM Item i1
  INNER JOIN Hetype ON i1.Type = Hetype.Type
  INNER JOIN StockTakeDetails ON i1.Itemref = StockTakeDetails.xItemID
  INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UID = StockTakeDetails.xUserSeen
  INNER JOIN EQLISTS ON i1.CurrentJob = EQLISTS.Eql_no
  INNER JOIN JOBS ON EQLISTS.Job_no = JOBS.JobNo
  INNER JOIN defcon ON JOBS.Status = defcon.Defcon_idx
WHERE JOBS."Due Back" >= TIMESTAMP '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND
  JOBS.Status <> 5 AND
  StockTakeDetails.IDX = (SELECT Max(s.IDX)
                          FROM StockTakeDetails s 
                          INNER JOIN Item i2 ON s.xItemID = i2.Itemref 
                          WHERE i2.Barcode = i1.Barcode)
```